# Sometimes can connect to remote server, sometimes not

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

It give me this error

```
 Warning: PDO::__construct() [<a href='pdo.--construct'>pdo.--construct</a>]: [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (trying to connect via tcp://xxxx.xxxx.xxx:3306)
```

But sometimes it is okay, no problem

Here is my code

```
    class Data
{
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->pdo = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=xxxx.xxx.xxx;
            dbname=xxxx;
            charset=utf8',
            'xxx',
            'xxx'
            );
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function Test($session_id)
    {
        //do something here
    }

    public function Test1($from, $to)
    {
        //do something here
    }
```

HOw can I fix this issue? Got confused because sometimes it works and sometimes not.

Any help or advice will be a big help thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details into the sometimes? As is, when you are home it works, when you travel it breaks, or on wifi it breaks, and on lan it works?

Comment: This is probably a problem on the receiving end. If it sometimes works for you, it means that your code is probably fine.

Comment: @mikemackintosh, im just doing it home. What I min is that when I first run, 2nd, 3rd run it is ok, the next run. its not. sometimes at the first 2nd run it is not ok but the next run it is ok again,.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, yeh because the same error always repeating. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what this message means is that the script was able to reach the server, but the port to which it needs to connect was either stalling or rejecting the request. Most of the time this happens because of a firewall issue or Anti Virus software. I guess what I am trying to say is that more than a coding issue, it is an infrastructure setup problem and you might need help from whoever manages your network/server

Comment: I have no Anti Virus, I stopped the firewall. Im using the arvixevps

Comment: I meant at the server side not your side. You might need the guys who manage the VPS to take a look... Actually their VPS page just redirects in loops causing an error in the browser..

Comment: they are probably rejecting the connection due to the number of requests you are making. This in addition to @raidenace.